# Raspberry Pi B V1.2 w/ 5'' HDMI

Tags: raspbian, pixel

I am trying so hard, to get this [octopi](https://octopi.octoprint.org/) to work. I have the B v1.2 with the 5inch 800*400 pixel. I cannot seem to get the GUI to work. After boot it hangs on Starting NTP Server, I type in Putty Startx and it spits out this:

```
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.8.11-2-ARCH armv7l Raspbian
Current Operating System: Linux raspberrypi 4.4.21-v7+ #911 SMP Thu Sep 15 14:22:38 BST 2016 armv7l
Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=0 dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=640 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=480 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa02082 bcm2709.serial=0xcd6ed80f smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:6E:D8:0F bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8 consoleblank=0 quiet
Build Date: 11 January 2016  01:32:44PM
xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1+rpi1 (http://www.debian.org/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.33.3
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Tue Feb  7 00:02:23 2017
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
modprobe: FATAL: Module g2d_23 not found.
```

Is it because I do not have the screen configured or what. I cannot find anywhere the right settings to even get into the GUI first let alone get octopi to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be clearer on exactly what it is you are doing?  What is an octopi?  What is the model of the screen you are using (with a link perhaps)?  Does a normal monitor work through the HDMI output? What OS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

```
mv /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbturbo.conf ~
```

solved it for me
(Or you can just delete 99-fbturbo.conf)